# C binary number in array to decimal

Tags: arrays, c, binary

What is happening inside the loop in `binary_array_to_numbers()`. I know what it is doing, I don't understand how its doing it though. First time seeing the use of `<<` and `|`. Thanks in advance.

```
unsigned binary_array_to_numbers(const unsigned *bits, size_t count) {
   unsigned res = 0;
   for (size_t i = 0; i < count; i++)
      res = res << 1 | bits[i];
   return res;
}

int main(void) {
   unsigned bits[] = {0, 0, 1, 0};
   unsigned received = binary_array_to_numbers(bits, sizeof(bits) / sizeof(bits[0]));
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with 'decimal'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The left shift operator `res << 1` shifts the res by 1 bit, so the the right-most bit is now zero.  Then you apply the bit-wise or operator `|` to set that right-most bit to the value of `bits[i]` (this assumes `bits` is an array of `0` or `1` and stored big-endian, if it's not your algorithm will not work).

Let's say `bits = { 1, 0, 1 }` (i.e. 5; it's more interesting than 2 in your example).  Here is what happens on each iteration:

0.

```
res = res << 1 | bits[0]
res = 0x0 << 1 | 1
res = 1
```

1. 

```
res = 1 << 1 | bits[1]
res = 0x2 | 0
res = 0x2
```

2. 

```
res = 0x2 << 1 | bits[2]
res = 0x4 | 1
res = 0x5
```

Answer (score 2):

##### Left Shift Operator

Left shift operator shifts all bits towards left by a certain number of specified bits. The bit positions that have been vacated by the left shift operator are filled with 0. The symbol of the left shift operator is `<<`.

##### Bitwise OR operator

The output of bitwise OR is 1 if at least one corresponding bit of two operands is 1. In C, bitwise OR operator is denoted by `|`.

Answer (score 2):

- `sizeof(bits) / sizeof(bits[0])` is a common method to use when you want to calculate the number of items of a fixed size array at compile-time. In this case the compiler will silently replace that whole expression with 4.
- The resulting integer type of a `sizeof` operation is the `size_t` type, which is a large unsigned integer suitable for describing array sizes etc. Therefore this type is used as parameter to the function.
- The array is passed to the function as `const unsigned *` which means it is read-only and won't get modified by the function. This is good practice and called *const correctness*.
- `res` in the function forms a binary bit-field.
- *Operator precedence* in the expression `res = res << 1 | bits[i];` gives `[]` over `<<` over `|` over `=`. That is, it's equivalent to:

  ```
  res = ( (res << 1) | bits[i] );
  ```
- `res << 1` shifts the previous stored result one bit to the left. At the first time of the loop this is all zeroes. When the value is shifted, a zero appears on the least significant bit (LSB).
- The bitwise OR `|` is taken between everything stored in `res` whatever is stored in `bits[i]`, which happens to be either 0 or 1 in this case, stored in the LSB of `bits[i]`.

  Since the rest of `bits[i]` is zero, only this LSB data matters for the OR. And in case of `res` we know that its LSB is zero. So in this specific case, it is the same as moving the contents of `bits[i]` into the LSB of `res`, without touching any other bits already stored in `res`.
- The result will be a binary bitfield of value `0010` or if you will hex `0x2`.